# Rails select date from an availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on an application, I actually implement a filter on my user index to search some users by : Language, city and availability(date). The filter by language and city work perfectly but not for the date.

index.html.erb :

```
<div>
  Date de départ :
  <%= f.text_field :with_start_time_gte, 'data-provide' => 'datepicker' %>
</div>
<%= f.submit 'Rechercher' %>
```

I create a model Availability with params (:name, :start_time, :end_time, :user_id)
User has_and_belongs_to_many :availability and availability belongs_to :user. I need that the filter search between the date between start_time and end_time of the availabilities and return the users available.

users_controller.rb :

```
  def index
@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
  User,
  params[:filterrific]
  #persistence_id: 'shared_key',
  #default_filter_params: {},
  #available_filters: [],
) or return
@users = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])

# Respond to html for initial page load and to js for AJAX filter updates.
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  # There is an issue with the persisted param_set. Reset it.
  puts "Had to reset filterrific params: #{ e.message }"
  redirect_to(reset_filterrific_url(format: :html)) and return
end
```

user.rb :

```
  filterrific(
default_filter_params: {},
available_filters: [
  :with_mother_tongue,
  :with_locality,
  :with_start_time_gte])

scope :with_mother_tongue, -> (search_string) {
where("users.mother_tongue LIKE ?", (search_string.to_s.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%'))
}

scope :with_locality, -> (search_string) {
where("users.locality LIKE ?", (search_string.to_s.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%'))
}

scope :with_start_time_gte, lambda { |ref_date|
where('users.availabilities.start_time >= ?', ref_date)
}
```

I think the problem is in the scope to take start_time from availabilities of user... But don't know how to do...
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

First, your relationship between `User` and `Availability` is wrong. An HABTM relation should be shared between the two models with a join table ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many))
Change to a `has_many/belongs_to` relationship if Availability just belongs to one User.

For your scope you have to join the relationship in the query:

```
scope :with_start_time_gte, -> (ref_date) { joins(:availabilities).where('availabilities.start_time >= ?', ref_date) }
```

Comment: I already CreateJoinTableUsersAvailabilities, I put User has_many availabilities and I put your scope and it's working ! Thank you for your help !